# Create a parameterized query using only a string

Tags: c#, sql-server

Ok, to avoid the "why are you doing it that way" comments and questions, let me explain that I am working in the confines of a very old app.  Long story short, I need to create a query with a parameter, and I need to pass it into a data access method as nothing but a string.

I can't pass anything but a string into this method, which will treat the string like a query and try to execute it against the sql-server-2008-r2 database.

Their method takes whatever string is sent to it and does an `EXEC(string)` in the database with it.

So, I am trying to figure out how to pass in a string that is safe from sql injection and which can still be executed.

So, for example, I can pass in this string:

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = '12345' "
```

And using SSMS (where I have read-only access) I can do this:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT * FROM myTable where myColum = @myColumn', 
    N'@myColumn nvarchar(250)', 
    @myColumn = N'12345'
```

In the C#, what I want to avoid is this:

```
string query = string.format("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = '{0}', var);
```

Again, back in SSMS, I am playing around with how to get this to work:

```
EXEC(????)
```

So, how do I create a single string that I can pass into this archaic method that will work inside of a SQL `EXEC()`?

I've tried this:

```
EXEC ('EXECUTE sp_executesql N''SELECT *  myTable where myColumn = @myColumn', N'@myColumn nvarchar(250)'', @myColumn = N''12345''')
```

But that gets me this:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I don't even know if that will work, and if it will, I don't know where my syntax error is.

**EDIT:**

Again in SSMS, this query works:

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE MyColumn = '12345')
```

I'm just not sure how to combine all of this so that it works with parameters when all I can do is pass in a single string.

**EDIT AGAIN:**

I see that I did a bad job of asking this question, so let me try again:

You can only pass a string into a method.  That string will be executed as follows in the DB:

```
EXEC(yourString).
```

My question is this:  Is it possible to pass in NOT just the actual query:

```
"select * from myTable where myColumn = '12345' "
```

But... is it possible to pass in a string that looks like this:

```
"EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT * from myTable WHERE myColumn = @myColumn', N'@myColumn nvarchar(250)', @myColumn = N'12345'"
```

For the record, I tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
EXEC ('EXECUTE sp_executesql N''SELECT * FROM mytable where myColumn = @myColumn'', N''@myColumn nvarchar(250)'', @myColumn = N''12345''    ')
```

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the help.  But, my question is: From within C#, I can only pass a string into the data access method. This doesn't help me build a string that I can send into the data access method.

Comment: sorry but I understood the question wrong, now I have corrected the answer :-)

Comment: So, what happens if instead of `12345`, the user enters `123'; drop table students; select '45`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didnt replace all the ' wiht '' -

```
EXEC ( 'EXECUTE sp_executesql N''SELECT * FROM myTable where myColum = @myColumn'', N''@myColumn nvarchar(250)'',  @myColumn = N''12345''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @myColumn nvarchar(75)
DECLARE @executeCommand nvarchar(1000)
SET @myColumn = '12345'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * from myTable where myColumn = @myColumn'
SET @executeCommand = 'EXECUTE sp_executesql N' + char(39) + @sqlCommand + char(39) + ', N''@myColumn nvarchar(75)'', @myColumn = '+ CHAR(39) + @myColumn + CHAR(39)
EXEC(@executeCommand)
```

Note that CHAR(39) concatening is because the variable @myColumn is declared as varchar.